# Send mail using cordova without default app

Tags: cordova, email

Is there a plugin that will allow me to send an email from my cordova app without having to use the default mail app. Just to be able to send the mail in the background. Lets say i want to send a mail from a gmail account to another gmail account

Comment: Use this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

Comment: i did read about that plugin, but it seems that i just opens the default mail app that is installed in the device, with whatever data you send it